# GLUT alternative in Java & Android?

Tags: java, opengl, opengl-es, glut, jogl

I noticed that GLUT is only available for C++.  I am looking to reuse my OpenGL code on Java, then again port it to Android.  Is there anything that is the 'standard' used instead of GLUT for these systems?

**Edit:**
I am in fact using JOGL and interested in reimplementing via Java and not reusing C++.  I have a basic understanding of C++, Java, and OpenGL, but nothing fancy yet.  I'm fine with trying to figure out everything about windows like resizing, coloring, etc.  I'm wondering if there's anything to help me with some of the (more advanced?) functions like glutSwapBuffers(), glutDisplayFunc(), glutMainLoop(), etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about [JOGL](https://jogamp.org/jogl/www/) or [LWJGL](http://www.lwjgl.org/) .Their APIs are 1:1 to C++ glut.If you use the fixed pipeline you also have [Glu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Utility_Library) lib with all you need inside.I didn't work with JOGL seriously because I didn't like the way it manages contexts and windows but I did do commercial projects with LWJGL and can tell this lib is fantastic.Also you can use it for mobile development.

I want to extend on this topic a little bit:

First , it seems like JOGL has got [GLUT class](http://download.java.net/media/jogl/jogl-2.x-docs/com/sun/opengl/util/gl2/GLUT.html) which takes care mostly  of primitives creation.Also I found [this](http://code.google.com/p/chrishobson-java/wiki/jreeglut) lib which is a partial port of C++ GLUT.But in fact , I don't understand your reason behind seeking GLUT C++ like lib.JOGL and LWJGL both supply you with input handling , context and window creation which are built in features.And in Java you will not probably be able to Unify context and windows creation under single roof because Android and Windows Java environments do it differently.Of course you can always roll your own class which will underneath take care of context/windows setup based on the platform but I think it is like re-inventing the wheel.

Regarding primitive geometry creation- I wouldn't bother to look into GLUT in such a case.Those are made using old ,deprecated (fixed) OpenGL pipeline.Today is 2013 and OpenGL is currently on 4.3 version and if you want to be synchronized with the current state of this technology and benefit from many new capabilities in OpenGL ,I would strongly recommend moving forward to OpenGL 3.3 onward.Doing this you need to code geometry manually.But there are many other benefits you gain like a total control over the way your rendering pipeline works.Also there are many online examples and tutorials on how create geometry for the programmable OpenGL.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I am currently using JOGL, but that only contains GL and GLU, not GLUT, which I also need.

Comment: What do you exactly need in GLUT ?

Comment: glutSwapBuffers(); glutInit; glutInitDisplayMode(); glutInit...();, glutCreateWindow(String); glutDisplayFunc(); glutMainLoop(), etc.  Those are what I can see at a glance.

Comment: Yes, your edited answer does help.  I'll keep it in mind while I see if anyone has any different answers.

Answer (score 1):

There is [jnigraphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605853/what-is-jni-graphics-or-how-to-use-it) and use [NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) to develop the native C code for Android.

Comment: I would prefer not to use the NDK if I don't have to.  I'm using this as a learning experience, hence why I'm porting to Java then Android, and I don't want to be dependent on the NDK to create an Android app.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

GLUT support is very limited in jogl, it definitely has no glutInitDisplayMode(). I suggest you to do the following:

### Simple way.

1. Figure out what is minimal set of glut functions you need;
2. Create a small dynamic library calling them for you;
3. Bridj that library and call the methods you need from your java app.

### More complex way.

1. Add needed functionality to jogl+gluegen, they have kind of code generator for that.

This way is imho more correct but:
(a) This is more work;
(b) jogl maintainers are not so friendly unfortunately, you will not be able to easily share work with community. First they will start blame you that your patch is piece of shit. Later they will almost command you to do in a way they need. In other words, it will take month for stupid emails... :)